# ACF Field select field add class if !=

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I've created this snippet of code below(which works): As you can see it's a bit clunky and I have copy and pasted for each module(x8). What would be the most effective way to streamline this? As I don't feel it's best practice?

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
(function($){
$(function() {

function addServiceStatusClass1(e){
if($('#MultiStream').text() != 'No Issues'){
    $('#ServiceStatus').addClass('Error');
    $('#ServiceTitle').addClass('Blocki');
 }else{
    $('#ServiceStatus').removeClass('Error');
    $('#ServiceTitle').removeClass('Blocki');
 }
}

$('#acf-field_5bf80363f0c0f').ready(addServiceStatusClass1);
$('#acf-field_5bf80363f0c0f').change(addServiceStatusClass1);

});
})( jQuery );
</script>

<script type ="text/javascript">
(function($){
$(function() {

function addServiceStatusClass2(e){
if($('#MobiStream').text() != 'Running 100%'){
    $('#ServiceStatus2').addClass('Error');
 }else{
    $('#ServiceStatus2').removeClass('Error');
 }
  }

 $('#acf-field_5c93c1061a218').ready(addServiceStatusClass2);
 $('#acf-field_5c93c1061a218').change(addServiceStatusClass2);

 });
})( jQuery );
</script>
```

Comment: Javascript is not java.

Comment: You should create a configuration object that contains the elements ids and the relevant validation/behaviour rules. Then iterate the object.

Comment: Do you have an example in Foo/Bar form?